# Unit Test- Count on object after doing an edit (MSTest)

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

The application that I'm testing is a simple app where notes are displayed for the user that created them.  I found a bug where if you edit the note it is removed from the users list of notes.  I'm trying to create a unit test that shows this by editing the note and then doing a count on the total notes.  I'm not sure how to do the count on an assert.  Here's what I have:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Edit_Note_Pass()
{
    HomeController target = new HomeController();
    var note = new NotePM();
    string text = "Note 1 Danielle " + DateTime.Now;
    note.Text = text;
    int id = note.NoteId;
    note.CreatedByUserName = Membership.GetUser("danielle").UserName;

    ActionResult actual;
    note.Text = text;
    actual = target.Create(note);
    actual = target.Edit(note.NoteId);

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));
    Assert.AreEqual(note.Text, text);        
}
```

Comment: You'll need the collections of notes in order to assert on them; where are they?

Comment: hmmm, I"m not sure.  Should I be creating them here?

Comment: Is the bug you are trying to capture in the HomeController class?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  The note list reloads and edited notes are not displayed for that user.

Comment: This might not be related, but check you have any sort of catching in place. Editing a note, then save, check the note is successfully saved. Also check when you repopulate the list, the source of the data has the note you edited. Check any conditions you may have which might filter out edited notes i.e Date modified etc.